# Understand the “Observer Pattern” with a real world example

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I was studying the Observer Pattern as documented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

I am new to Software Development and got my head banging while understanding the design patterns. Please, help me understand the Observer Pattern. Could someone give a use-case example of where this is useful in the real world?

Comment: Nowadays in modern langages it's implemented as events. It's a matter of who is handling a référence on who.

Comment: @Romka can u please explain in terms of a use case

Comment: In Java Swing, when you create a button (JButton), you can register an ActionListener (Observer) with the button.  When the user left-clicks the button, all registered ActionListeners are notified and the actionPerformed method of the ActionListener is executed.